# Generate 5 character unique id from 14 character string

Tags: java

I have 14 characters unique input string like `BR004395285678` and I want to map it to few 5 character unique `ids`. Is there any way to do this except using auto-incremented ids?

Comment: post a sample output you expecter for 5 characters from the above `BR004395285678 `

Comment: If you have more than n^5 ids, where n is the number of symbols in your alphabet, you'll have collisions. if you use randomization you'll probably end up with collisions approximately after n^2 insertions, or even earlier.

Comment: Specify the format of the input string. What are the possible chars in it? Does it always start with BR or with BR00 etc.? These are important things related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

1) In general, you cannot have 100% guarantee that the 5 char strings will be unique.
That's because the 14 chars string can be more than all the possible 5 char ones.
That is assuming that the alphabets of the 5-char and 14-char strings are the same.

2) In practice, if some of the chars in the 14 char strings are meaningless
(i.e. are always the same across the whole set of 14 char strings) then you
can use a simple mapping like e.g.

BR00 43952 85678 -> 85678

in order to come up with a set of 5-char strings.

For this idea with a simple mapping, use that part of your 14-char strings
which is most variable, most varying across the 14-char stings set (normally
that would be the part that consists of the last 5 digits).

3) The best solution is to use a different alphabet for your 5 char strings.

E.g. add a leading 0 to BR00 43952 85678. You get 
0BR 004 395 285 678.
Break this into groups of 3 chars as shown above.
Now encode each triple through a bijection into a char/symbol from another
(bigger) alphabet. What you get will be guaranteed to be 5-char and unique.

Answer (score 0):

You have 26^2 * 10^12 unique possibilities and you this you need at least 6.8*10^14 symbols to represent it needing 50 bits of information. i.e. 7 bytes.  You can use by 4 characters if you assume each character is 16-bit (avoiding invalid ones) but is this what you had in mind?

As peter.petrov suggests, if you break the string into AA DDD DDD DDD DDD and you can encode 1000 symbols per character using 16-bit characters, you would use 5 characters instead of 4 as above.